# How to determine object orientation in image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am supposed to determine the direction of a boat from drone imagery, whether it's docked from the front or from the back

I tried to split the bbox of the boat image, use binary images by thresholding the boat bbox,
and i tried to split the bbox into two half, calculate the sum of blue pixels in every half sinc the front part of the boat will have more water i the image due to the triangle shape, but it didn't work
My question is, how can I determine the correct direction of the boat using image processing techniques

Comment: Have you tried to create custom labeled categories and measure probability of being either front or back? I have a feeling that the above logic you use may not always work, it highly depends on dataset though.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i was thinking to do a binary classification to see if the boat is left or right, but I thought about looking first about some classic vision techniques, since using an object detction model won't work due to the data augmentation while training that will flip the image.

Comment: Can you show an example of image? It could help to find an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use semantic segmentation to detect the dock
and a keypoint method to detect the boats, this method is usually used for face recognition but I think it would help in your case

Answer (score 1):

I used this [TensorFlow library](https://github.com/ivan-alles/localizer) to detect object orientation in many projects. You need to train a neural network on your images. Then it will predict both boat location and direction.